# how to check condition for json array elements

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, android-studio

I am developing an app in which i am calling a service, in which data is coming as an array format.
As shown below:

```
[  
 {  
  "Image":null,
  "FirstName":null,
  "Active":false,
  "HallTicketNumber":0,
  "ReportingTime":null,
  "EventDetails":null,
  "CompanyName":null,
  "Designation_Role":null,
  "EventDate":null,
  "StateName":null,
  "CityName":null,
  "FullAddress":null,
  "HallTicket_Status":"HETSTOP"
 }
]
```

In that i need to check the condition for **HET_STATUS**,if that StATUS is **HET STOP** then it should print that het stop. But **when i am trying to check the condition it is showing nothing**:

Below is my code:

```
  String StringData = "" + data;
  try {
          JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
          int len = rootArray.length();
          for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
               JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);

               String CompanyName = json.optString("CompanyName ");
               String Position = json.optString("Designation_Role");
               String EventDate = json.optString("EventDate");
               String StateName = json.optString("StateName ");
               String CityName = json.optString("CityName");
               String Address = json.getString("FullAddress");
               String ReportingTime = json.getString("ReportingTime");
               String HallTicket_Status = json.getString("HallTicket_Status");

               if (HallTicket_Status == "HETSTOP") {
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UpcomingEventsDetails.this, "HET STOP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                   toast.show();
```

Comment: Use `HallTicket_Status.equalsIgnoreCase("HETSTOP")`

Comment: Yes ,I got it.Thankyou

Comment: Np. Wel come !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
if(HallTicket_Status.equalsIgnoreCase("HETSTOP")){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UpcomingEventsDetails.this, "HET STOP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}else{
    //do something
}
```

**boolean equals(String str):** Case sensitive comparison

**boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String str):** Case in-sensitive comparison

**`==` will still test object equality**.  It is easy to be fooled, however:

```
Integer a = 10;
Integer b = 10;

System.out.println(a == b); //prints true

Integer c = new Integer(10);
Integer d = new Integer(10);

System.out.println(c == d); //prints false. however:

Integer a = 10;
Integer b = 10;

System.out.println(a == b); //prints true

Integer c = new Integer(10);
Integer d = new Integer(10);

System.out.println(c == d); //prints false
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==` condition for strings. Instead of use `str.equals("HEYSTOP")` . This will return boolean. If you check string is null then you should use `==` or `!=` conditions.